Nuxt 3 Composables Not Defined
Functions in files in the composables directory are not being auto-imported and are undefined.
I am on Windows, using VS Code.
I have explicitly enabled imports in the nuxt.config.ts:
imports: {
    autoImport: true,
  },

I have tried explicitly / manually importing the composable from #imports
import { useGeolocation } from "#imports";

However, it is clear that the relevant composable is not present in .nuxt imports directory.
I have deleted the .nuxt directory and node-modules and reinstalled / rebuilt.
I have copied the official Nuxt 3 composables example here, but that also does not work.
I have checked the read/write privileges of the project directory and its subdirectories.
Components are auto-importing from the components directory.

Please give a minimal reproduction. Otherwise it will be hard for others to help you.
